# Project hangs on QProcess::start when starting QtAssistant

Tags: qt, qt-assistant

I am using `QProcess::start` to launch `Qt Assistant` with my custom help project file. It works fine until i load project(not help project file) to my programm. Programm generates images from specific data using custom library. Even when all processes ends and i see generated images and nothing else happens, when i trying to launch Qt Assistant, my programm hangs at `QProcess:start` function when trying to start process. The code is:

`show()` function(public):

```
if (!run())
    return false;
QByteArray ba("setSource ");
ba.append("qthelp://insyn_help/doc/");

proc->write(ba + page.toLocal8Bit() + '\n');
return true;
```

`run()` function(private):

```
if (!proc)
    proc = new QProcess();
if (proc->state() == QProcess::Running)
    return true;
QString app = QString(QT_BIN_DIR) + QDir::separator() + QString("assistant");
QString path = QString(PREFIX) + QString(HELP_INSTALL_PATH) + QString("/help_project.qhc");
QStringList args;
args << QLatin1String("-collectionFile")
     << QLatin1String(path.toLatin1())
     << QLatin1String("-enableRemoteControl");

QFileInfo help_project(path);
if (help_project.exists()) {
    proc->start(app,args);
    if (!proc->waitForStarted()) {
        m_exitCode = 1;
        emit closed();
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code is a part of `AssistantLauncher` class which was registered using `qmlRegisterType` and added to `main.qml` as a member of application window. My programm doesn't touch it anywhere (except calling a method `show()`). It is separate object (except it is a part of `appWindow`). The question is why does the process can not start only after my programm did some work? And why `QProcess::start` even dont have timeout.

UPD: I moved `proc->start(app,args);` to the child process, which i getting by using fork() and now my programm hangs on `pid_t child = fork().` So the problem is that new process can not be created.

Comment: I tried to launch something else (chromium-browser, for example), but the same thing happened.

Comment: More at https://forum.qt.io/topic/94973/project-hangs-on-qprocess-start-when-starting-qtassistant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to do not use `fork()` because it is dangerous in big projects. More at http://www.evanjones.ca/fork-is-dangerous.html . `posix_spawn` also hangs my project. Now i decided to `fork()` new process at the beginning and send commands to it through the pipe.